# How to run sagemaker ML pipeline automatically every week

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I just started working with AWS SageMaker . My requirement is to create an ML pipeline in SageMaker that will download data from s3, train the data with custom model, deploy the model back to s3. These 3 steps need to run automatically every week without any human intervention. I assume this is possible and am looking for proper resources that can help me create this. Can someone please guide me with this? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For building the pipeline you can use SageMaker pipelines. You can find an example here - https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/abalone_build_train_deploy/sagemaker-pipelines-preprocess-train-evaluate-batch-transform.ipynb

Once you have the pipeline built you can trigger the pipeline using Amazon EventBridge integration which supports both event based or schedule based events. Check the below link to setup using event bridge
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pipeline-eventbridge.html

Comment: Can I also acquire the same using Studio Projects?

Comment: yeah pipelines are part of Projects.